# encoding hebrew in mailto: anchor element

Tags: encoding, href, mailto, hebrew

I have a mailto link with hebrew text in the body parameter.

I am getting gibberish as a result.

example result:

```
׳©׳ ׳”׳׳™׳¨׳•׳¢: 
׳׳×׳—׳™׳: 11.05.2011
׳׳¡׳×׳™׳™׳: 09.04.2014
׳”׳¢׳¨׳•׳×
```

I can fix this by adding `requestEncoding="windows-1255"` 
in the `web config`.
but this causes unwanted side effects in the rest of the site.

How can I get proper hebrew text in the mail body?

Comment: can you share the produced html head and the mailto anchor

Comment: HEAD:

<head><title>
</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="he-IL" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head> 

ANCHOR:  

<a class="a-sendEvent" id="aEventMailto" href="mailto:?body=שם האירוע: fixing the encoding issue 27.12.11%0Aמתחיל: 11.05.2011%0Aמסתיים: 09.04.2014%0Aהערות: encoding was messed up here as well%0A&subject=fixing the encoding issue 27.12.11">

Answer (score 0):

try this in your href:

```
mailto:?body=&#1513;&#1501; &#1492;&#1488;&#1497;&#1512;&#1493;&#1506;: fixing the encoding issue 27.12.11%0A&#1502;&#1514;&#1495;&#1497;&#1500;: 11.05.2011%0A&#1502;&#1505;&#1514;&#1497;&#1497;&#1501;: 09.04.2014%0A&#1492;&#1506;&#1512;&#1493;&#1514;: encoding was messed up here as well%0A&subject=fixing the encoding issue 27.12.11
```

I played around with this link:
http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/convert-to-html.php

Comment: thank you rene. I just created a new test website using same head and anchor element, and there is no encoding problem.  There must be something in the web config , or another element on the page, that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should encode your Hebrew text body before sending the e-mail.

i.e:

```
    final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setText(message, "utf-8");
    msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

    MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    mbp1.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSourcemessage.toString), "text/html")));
    mbp1.setContent(new String(message.getBytes("UTF8"),"ISO-8859-8-i"), "text/html");

    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
    msg.setContent(mp, "text/html");
```

**worked fine for me :)**

good luck !

Dave.